# Wallpaper crashes sometimes in Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, desktop-customization

Some days ago I re-installed Windows 10 on my laptop and now, sometimes, after:

- Quitting a 3d game
- Waking (Resume from sleep)
- Power on

wallpaper become like this:

[image: screenshot of desktop]

Videocard info:

- GeForce MX230
- Driver Version: 441.37
- CUDA Version: 10.2
- GPU Memory: 2048MiB

This is the first time I've had this problem.

Maybe I can set some setting?

Comment: According to https://www.geforce.com/drivers the latest driver is version 445.75 (x64).

Comment: @simonatrcl it hasn't helped me